# I don't know what the path format is on OS X so I can write a .csv file using Java

Tags: java, macos, csv, filewriter, bufferedwriter

My goal is to write a csv file to a specific location on my computer. The problem is that I keep getting the `FileNotFoundException` error when I compile my program. I know my where my problem is.

Its here,

`FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("://Users/michaelrichards/NetBeansProjects/UniProject/src");`

Can someone please tell me the format when typing out a path in terminal.

```
import java.io.*;
public class WriteToFile
{
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException
{
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("://Users/michaelrichards/NetBeansProjects/UniProject/src");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    String myArray[] = {"one", "two", "three"};
    String writableString = "";

    for(String item : myArray)
    {
        writableString += item + ",";
    }

    writableString = writableString.substring(0, writableString.length() - 1);

    bw.write(writableString);
    bw.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a Mac user, but as far as I know, your path should be `/Users/michealrichards/...`.  You could also use the Java system property `user.home` to get the home directory of the current user, independent of the platform:

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/NetBeansProjects/UniProject/src";
```

*Edit:* I just noticed that you are trying to open a *directory* (`src`) as a *file*! This won't work anyway. You have to pass a path to a file to the `FileWriter` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

OS X is a Unix based system so your path should be

> /Users/michaelrichards/NetBeansProjects/UniProject/src

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Windows use like D://Folder/folder/raghu.txt

in linux /home/(user name)/Desktop/raghu.txt

Comment: Could this possibly answer the question less?